# Excel - Formula to figure if the price of a product has changed over time

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Would like to inquire on the following:

I would like to create a formula to determine if the price of a product has changed over time.

I have attached an image below.

Logically, I would have to use the start dates, since some of the (end) dates overlap.

But how can I compare the prices associated with the current start date with a previous start date, and return a Yes, No, or Not Applicable (earliest date, no previous date to compare with).

Thank you.

[Formula to determine if price has changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AqZrx.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method uses a combination of `IF()`, `IFERROR()` and `VLOOKUP()` and assumes your data is in `chronological` order. If it is not in `chronological` order then you will need to sort it by `START DATE` or find an alternative solution.

Add this formula to `Cell E2`and drag down to the other cells:

```
=IFERROR(IF(VLOOKUP(A2;A3:B7;2;FALSE)=B2;"No";"Yes");"Not Applicable")
```

[image]

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.